# How to make a member function in an inheritance hierarchy return always the same value?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have an inheritance hierarchy and I want to make each class in this hierarchy have a set of attributes which are particular for that class and which do not change during the run of the program. For example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    const std::string getName() const;
    bool getAttribute1() const;
    int getAttribute2() const;
};
```

Now I want these functions to return the same result all the time. Furthermore, when another class inherits `Base` this class should have its own set of attributes and any instance of this derived class should have the same attributes. Also the name should be unique for each class.

I want to know a way to make this as transparent and elegant as possible. Sofar I have considered 2 ideas that I can use:

1. Make some lock system.

That is provide setters for these attributes, but make them throw a runtime exception when they are called more than once.

1. Make the getters pure virtual.

In this case, the result of the functions would not be stored inside the object itself. This would make it vaguely clear that the result depends on the dynamic type.

Both ideas sound incredibly lousy, so I need your help.

I am new to C++, but I know there are a lot of idioms and patterns to solve general problems like this one. Do you know any?

Comment: You need to better think about what you are trying to do (and mention what it is of course). What is exactly the problem with pure virtual? Why does it sound lousy?

Comment: I am trying to make a hierarchy of genetic algorithms. They have a lot in common, therefore I represent them as objects and each algorithm should have a unique name. The problem with virtual functions is that it is not as self-explanatory that they always return the same value as with e.g. const static members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an inheritance hierarchy and I want to make each class in this hierarchy have a set of attributes which are particular for that class and which do not change during the run of the program

Well, then just provide the corresponding values as arguments to a class constructor, and do not expose any setter method on the public interface. This will make sure the values remain constant throughout the life-time of the object.

To protect against possible errors that would alter the value of those data members from member functions of your class (which of course can access the private data), make those data members `const`. Notice, that this will force you to initialize those members in the constructor's initializer list.

```
class Base
{
public:
    // Forwarding constructor (requires C++11)
    Base() : Base("base", true, 42) { }
    const std::string getName() const { return _s; }
    bool getAttribute1() const { return _a1; }
    int getAttribute2() const { return _a2; }

protected:
    // Constructor that can be called by derived classes
    Base(std::string s, bool a1, int a2)
    : _s(s), _a1(a1), _a2(a2) { }

private:
    const std::string _s;
    const bool _a1;
    const bool _a2;
};
```

Derived classes would then just construct the base subobject with the appropriate arguments:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // Provide the values for the constant data members to the base constructor
    Derived() : Base("derived", false, 1729) { }
};
```

This way you would not incur in the overhead of a virtual function call, and you won't have to rewrite similar virtual functions for each of these members in derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

Make them virtual and hard-code the result which the functions should return:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual const std::string getName() const { return "BaseName"; }
    virtual bool getAttribute1() const { return whatEverAttributeValueYouWant; }
    virtual int getAttribute2() const { return attributeValueHere; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual const std::string getName() const { return "DerivedName"; }
    virtual bool getAttribute1() const { return whatEverOtherAttributeValueYouWant; }
    virtual int getAttribute2() const { return otherAttributeValueHere; }
};
```

If you want to describe *classes* rather than objects, use (kind-of) traits:

```
template<class T> struct AttributeValues;

template<> struct AttributeValues<Base> {
    static const std::string name () { return "BaseName"; }
};

template<> struct AttributeValues<Derived> {
    static const std::string name () { return "DerivedName"; }
};

//...

auto nameBase = AttributeValues<Base>::name ();
auto nameDerived = AttributeValues<Derived>::name ();
```